# Cosa significa "froppata"?

Tags: word-meaning

Nella versione in italiano del monologo *Il primo miracolo di Gesú Bambino* di *Mistero buffo*, di Dario Fo, ho letto:

> – Non so io. Eravamo qui che si giocava... Guarda mamma, ho fatto il mio primo 
>   miracolo... è ancora caldo!
>   
>         – Un bambino di terra?! L’hai fatto tu?
>    
>         – No, no, è lui giusto com’è nato... Era cattivo, m’ha fatto offesa carogna... Dopo che m’ha sfasciato tutti i giochi l’ho fatto di terra... una **froppata** di fuoco: bruciato! Terracotta!

Non so cosa sia una "froppata": non ho trovato questo termine in nessun dizionario. Qualcuno di voi me lo saprebbe spiegare? Si tratta di un termine di origine dialettale?

Nella versione originale che, secondo afferma lo stesso Fo, è scritta in «un linguaggio che è l'insieme di parecchi dialetti del Nord, tra i quali prevale il veneto», l'espressione «una froppata di fuoco» corrisponde a «'na fropàda de fògo».

Comment: Potrebbe essere d'aiuto riportare anche la versione in grammelot, se ce l'hai, perché è probabilmente più vicina alla parola originale.

Comment: Dario Fo ha adoperato centinaia di parole inventate nei suoi drammi; non credo sia il caso di aprire un filone per ciascuna. La parola in questione non significa nulla: quelle parole inventate vogliono suggerire qualcosa all'ascoltatore che è libero di interpretarle come crede. È possibile che ci sia un'origine da qualche dialetto, ma spesso è solo una vaga onomatopea.

Comment: @DenisNardin: Fatto.

Comment: @DenisNardin: Veramente la lingua originale di questo racconto non è "grammelot" (colpa mia che precedentemente avevo usato il termine "grammelot" in modo incorretto, ma l'ho già corretto), ma "un linguaggio che è l'insieme di parecchi dialetti del Nord, tra i quali prevale il veneto". Se fosse grammelot,  egreg avrebbe ragione.

Comment: @egreg: Quello che dici è così quando Dario Fo adopera il grammelot. Ma questo testo non è grammelot: è la traduzione all'italiano, fatta dallo stesso Fo, di un testo che non è neanche in grammelot. Fo lo spiega molto bene nel libro *Mistero buffo* (Einaudi), se uno legge tutti i prologhi e le introduzioni. E quando traduce in italiano cerca che il testo sia comprensibile ai traduttori in lingua straniera: per questa ragione spesso scrive parole fra parentesi quadre (anche questo viene spiegato nel libro).

Comment: L'unica cosa che mi viene in mente è il francese *frapper*, colpire (possibilmente collegato al veneto *fracar*?).

Comment: @DenisNardin: In italiano esiste anche [frappare](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/F/frappare.php) che sembra potesse significare [ferire](https://books.google.es/books?id=Y2ReAAAAcAAJ&pg=PR23&lpg=PR23&dq=%22Rinaldo+gli+ha+frappata+la+persona%22&source=bl&ots=LucRKoK23r&sig=v-NKWI7s9n_qi7yIvRIGx8Rwxb0&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiun7u8o9DYAhXCOBQKHVSFDlcQ6AEICzAA#v=onepage&q=%22Rinaldo%20gli%20ha%20frappata%20la%20persona%22&f=false).

Comment: @egreg: Tuttavia, ammetto che, persino nei testi di Fo tradotti in italiano, possa avere qualche parola inventata e che possa essere il caso di questo vocabolo. Comunque, è molto difficile per me accorgermi se un certo termine sia inventato o meno. Ho fatto molte domande su parole provenienti di testi in italiano di Fo e in quasi tutti i casi qualcuno è riuscito a trovare il significato.

Answer (score 1):

Dario Fo crea un linguaggio espressivo e immaginifico che dà voce al personaggio, in un processo di costruzione del *pastiche* che va ben oltre il confine della ricostruzione filologica. Fo non si fa scrupolo di piegare la
storia, ivi compresa quella linguistica, alle esigenze della scena e del messaggio sociopolitico che essa veicola. Basti pensare, in Mistero Buffo, all'ardita esegesi del contrasto di Cielo D'Alcamo.

Nel teatro di Fo il rapporto fra la lingua nazionale e l'elemento locale è complesso e dinamico. Lungo l'asse che unisce i due poli dell'italiano standard unitario e la moltitudine dei vernacoli, la mescolanza di questi due elementi produce una vasta gamma di configurazioni linguistiche.

Scrive [Graziano Benelli](https://www.openstarts.units.it/bitstream/10077/13968/1/benelli_LozanoFOonline.pdf)

> Né si dovrà dimenticare **l’originalità della lingua con cui sono composti e recitati questi testi, una lingua che Dario Fo ha scelto, se non inventato, con grande abilità**;  si  tratta  di  una  imitazione  dell’italiano  arcaico  che  si  suppone  parlato  nella  Pianura Padana o in una parte di questa. **L’invenzione di una tale lingua, tra l’altro molto comprensibile in tutta la nostra penisola, è già di per sé fonte di straniamento e di grande comicità**. Se leggiamo la versione in un italiano odierno di Mistero Buffo, che a un certo punto Dario Fo ha inserito a fronte del testo originale per meglio aiutare la sua fruibilità *[È probabile che tale versione sia stata effettuata soprattutto per far conoscere Mistero Buffo all’estero e per facilitare la sua traduzione nelle altre lingue. Anche la numerosa accentuazione delle parole, assente nella prima edizione dei testi, va in questa direzione.]*, avremo subito l’impressione di un lavoro diverso, 
>   meno avvincente, meno entusiasmante; la versione in un italiano corrente perde di molto lo smalto originale, fino a diventare in taluni passi quasi banale.
>
> La particolarità della lingua, che *appare al pubblico come un italiano per così dire storpiato, dialettale e dunque popolare*, produce già un effetto straniante che va nella direzione della comicità; questa lingua anticata più che antica predispone lo spettatore ad accettare un contenuto anche alternativo alla cultura finora appresa.
>
> La traduzione in un italiano attuale dà origine a un testo profondamente diverso, a  tal  punto  che  non  sembra  neppure  dire  la  stessa  cosa;  e  in  effetti  si  tratta  di  tutt’altra atmosfera, di un clima molto diverso che non aiuta lo spettatore/lettore a immergersi in una visione alternativa a quella proposta dalla cultura ufficiale.

Dario Fo si è costruito una lingua con termini provenienti da zone diverse e suoni scelti in base al criterio del fonosimbolismo. Mistero Buffo è scritto in uno «pseudodialetto padano-veneto» quattro-cinquecentesco, frutto della ricettività e della creatività verbale del grande autore-interprete.

Sarà difficile trovare in un dizionario, e forse bisognerebbe evitare di farlo, i termini che si discostano dall'italiano standard, che pur si comprendono, usati da chi come Dario Fo ha passato la vita a impastare idiomi provenienti da tutta la penisola, carichi di suoni onomatopeici, forme traslate, sempre sostenute dal gesto e da una straordinaria vocalità.

Qui "una froppata di fuoco", dove *froppata* non è un termine italiano ma semplicemente la versione italianizzata di *fropàda*, suscita l'idea di una "fiammata" e credo sia questo il significato che le si può attribuire.